# Get 'hamburger icon' to float right in nav bar, Bootstrap 4

Tags: navbar, bootstrap-4

I've created a nav bar that collapses, based on the browser size. I cannot seem to stop the nav bar from stacking, and the icon goes beneath the nav bar brand when the browser size is reduced. I would like to get it to show on the right side of the nav bar, rather than underneath the brand.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-white fixed-top navbar-custom" id="mainNav">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#home">
        <img class="logo" src="img/unicornActive.png" onmouseover="hover(this);" onmouseout="unhover(this);" alt="logo">
    </a>

    <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-left" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
<span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>

</button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent" role="navigation">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link active" href="#home" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#about" data-toggle="tab">About</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#work" data-toggle="tab">Work</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#technique" data-toggle="tab">Technique</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#contact" data-toggle="tab">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Any help would be really appreciated! I've tried floating it right and it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Try removing the `navbar-toggler-left` class.

Comment: I don't have the problem you're describing in the latest version of the bootstrap beta. What version of bootstrap 4 are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Which version of bootstrap and jquery do you use?
I created an instance on jsfiddle with the newest version of the bootstrap framework and I do not get your issue.

```
https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css
https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js
https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js
```

[JSFiddler](https://jsfiddle.net/0815g9ja)